# How to Make a Web Application Work Online, and Offline

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, codeigniter-3

I recently built a web application for my company, but the client needed the application to work both offline and online, depending on the availability of internet connection.

Anyways, I'm looking for a way to allow my application to run offline and online. The following technologies are used: PHP, MySQL, jQuery, HTML, and CSS.

Clients could be using that app without internet connection; if there is internet connection the app will automatically move to using the hosting server.

Answer (score 0):

This is either trivial or insanely difficult, depending on a few things:

1. Does your client have an internal network it can use?
2. Can that internal network be accessed from the outside?
3. How many users will your application have?
4. Are they all on the same network?

On the trivial end of the scale, you can host the entire application locally on your client's network, that can also be accessed from outside, if there is an internet connection. But if there isn't as long as you're on the internal network, the service continues.

On the insanely difficult end, you can build your service so that each browser stores enough information on the machine to allow the user to continue to use the service even if internet connection drops. And then when the connection resumes, the service syncs any updates to the browser.

But this all depends on the answers to those questions.